# How to display image from ContentVersion object in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, images

how can i display image coming from ContentVersion object in datatable using lightning web component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options to implement it.

If you know `ContentVersion` `Id`, you could just create a link and include `img` tag with `src` attribute to that link.

Another option to query for `VersionData` and display image based on `VersionData`. However, this option is more complicated.

For example, to implement the first option one could write the following code

> Listing of `imageDisplay.html`

```
<template>
    <lightning-input onchange={inputChange}></lightning-input>
    <template if:true={imageUrl}>
        <img src={imageUrl}/>
    </template>    
</template>
```

> Listing of `imageDisplay.js`

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class ImageDisplay extends LightningElement {
    @track imageUrl;
    inputChange(e) {
        if (e.target.value)
            this.imageUrl = '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'  + e.target.value
    }
}
```

> Listing of `imageDisplay.js-meta.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="imageDisplay">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Next, go ahead an upload some content, for example, some image that can be posted to your coworker for birthday occasion who likes both Star Wars and Force.com and check its `Id` or query for it.

In my case, `Id` of the content version I have uploaded is `0681t000005tiKe`, for your case it would be different.

Next, go ahead and place your component somewhere to see it, for example, on the home page and save it and activate it.

Next, go to your home page (or any page you have placed your component), and insert the id of Content Version.

Voila!

[image]

Comment: Hello @Patlatus thank you for your replying please can you tell me how did you set the URL of the image in Javascript file (based on what did you choose this URL)

Comment: when you open the ContentVersion file and inspect the link it has, you can get that URL. Also several URL are mentioned in other answers like https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148524/how-to-display-image-in-lightning-component-from-contentdocumentlink?rq=1

Comment: @sallyyamak if this answer answers your question, please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: another question please after i insert the image(ContentVersion) through the apex class it still not available on preview what supposed to be the problem

Comment: @sallyyamak if this is a different question please consider creating a different question. If you insert ContentVersion through Apex, then you know ID of it after insert and you can return that Id to Lightning

Comment: my problem is that after insert of contentversion if i go to contentVersion file i see all the contentVersion that i uploaded but when i click to preview the image it will displays that the image in not available

Comment: @sallyyamak I think this question and answer has the code you need: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249164/how-to-insert-contentversion-with-preview-in-files - try to check if you follow and if you populate VersionData field.

Comment: please i want to ask you a question how can i run a java class in eclipse through salesforce Apex?

Comment: There is already such question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934137/how-to-run-single-java-file-from-a-project-in-eclipse To run a specific piece of Java code, you should consider creating a main method in that class that just launches some specific piece of code under the constraints that you'd like. One way to do this would be to add a method public static void main(String[] args) containing the code you want to run. Once you've done this, you can right-click on it, choose the "Run as..." option, and select "Java application" to run the program you've written.

Comment: thank you for your replying but my question is how to run java class (exist in eclipse) through an Apex class

Comment: @sallyyamak it is not possible to run Java in Salesforce (Force.com). If you need to run Java, consider using heroku service acquired by Salesforce.

Comment: So you can store your Java class on heroku and make it available to be called by some external REST OR SOAP service and then you could execute that external REST OR SOAP service to execute Java on heroku